# How to get the text property of a hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

There is no .Text property on hyperlink in WPF

looking to get the text in the click event and the only way so far is

```
Run r = hyperlink.Inlines.First() as Run;
gotText( r.Text );
```

Somehow this seems rather convoluted given that hyperlinks do have a text/content

Or is this an oversight or perhaps there's a better reason why this property does not exist ?

Comment: Could you give the namespace of the class you are using that has this Hyperlink Object? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx does have the property you are looking for so it must be a different class specific for WPF.

**EDIT** never mind. Just found the appropriate class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx

Comment: @KavetKerek, that's in ~web.ui, the Q is for WPF

Comment: Yes I found the appropriate library, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Hyperlink control is derived from the TextElement Class. Specifically it is supposed to be a control that is able to sit within flow content. While one might initially view the control as something simple like a TextBox, but in order for the Hyperlink control to fit nicely within FlowContent it needs to have a similar structure to other flow content elements.

For more on FlowContent take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is because a hyperlink can potentially have multiple runs of text.